# PHP - Get data from database then fetch it again

Tags: php, while-loop, duplicates

I am trying to get data from database then fetch it again with different mysql_query using while() in both query , but the problem it is producing results more than one time because i used while in first query . So any answer to get all data without while() for first query ?

```
$AllFrnd = "SELECT friend , followers FROM frndlist WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION[' user_id ']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
$getfrnd = mysql_query($AllFrnd);
while($frnd = mysql_fetch_array($getfrnd)) {
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE (userid ='".$frnd['friend']."') OR (userid =       '".$frnd['followers']."') OR (userid = '".$_SESSION[' user_id ']."') ORDER BY id DESC";
    $rs = mysql_query($query2);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        echo ''.$row['content'].'';
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
// Associative array

   $frnd =mysql_fetch_array($getfrnd,MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

then get your data as like :

```
echo $frnd ["friend"]
echo $frnd ["followers"]
```

And you should use `mysqli_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query just like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM post
WHERE userid IN (
    SELECT followers
    FROM frndlist
    WHERE userid = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'
)
OR userid IN (
    SELECT friend
    FROM frndlist
    WHERE userid = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'
)
OR userid = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easyly handle by using this function

```
function sel($table,$field="*", $condition="1",$sort="" ){
    if($sort!='') $sort="order by $sort ";
    //echo "select $field  from $table where $condition $sort ";
    $sel_query=mysql_query("select $field  from $table where $condition $sort ");
    //$sel_result=array();
    while($temp_res=@mysql_fetch_array($sel_query))
    {
        $sel_result[]=$temp_res;
    }
    return isset($sel_result)?$sel_result: 0;
}


while($frnd = mysql_fetch_array($getfrnd)) {
    $temp_res=sel("post","*"," (userid ='".$frnd['friend']."') OR (userid =       '".$frnd['followers']."') OR (userid = '".$_SESSION[' user_id ']."') ORDER BY id DESC");
    if($temp_res)foreach($temp_res as $row){
        echo $row['content'];
    }
}
```